# Inverting a phrase and write it weirdly with c

Tags: c

my programming teacher have sent some exercises for practice, and this one I've no clue for a way to solve it.

In his example, he asks: write a program that gets a phrase or a word, turn it backwards and write it weirdly.

I'm trying to use the phrase "ABCDE" write it backwards and then, start writing the phrase from the middle.

In the end, he wants something like: CBAED

All I have so far, is the phrase/word backwards, like: EDCBA

Well, this is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inverter();
int main(){

    printf("sentence to revert: "); 
    inverter();
    return 0;
}

void inverter(){

    char letra;
    scanf("%c",&letra);
    if( letra != '\n'){

        inverter();
        printf("%c",letra);
    }
}
```

As you guys have seen, I'm a newbie in C (and in English) so, if any of you could give me a way to proceed, I would appreciate it a lot.

Edit: I believe I was not happy on the phrase I've selected as an exemple, so I've changed it.

Comment: What is `Reverse()`? Is it supposed to be `inverter()`?

Comment: The final output could be *backwards this write*. It's hard telling what your teacher wants.

Comment: Weather, its inverter, sorry.

Comment: R Sahu, he wants that the new sentence to start in the middle, run backwards and finish in the middle, like Hello, would be leHol. My english is not so good, so is a little difficult to explain what I want, I hope you understand this time.

Comment: But your code does nothing - it echoes each character. What are you asking of us?

Comment: Explain what he wants in portuguese for me, Im guessing thats your native language

Comment: Victor: Yes, it is. Oi Victor, então, um dos exercicios era que eu fizesse um programa que invertesse uma palavra ou frase. No exercicio seguinte, eu pegaria essa frase e, ela estando invertida, faria com que ela começasse no meio, e então ela "andaria ao contrário, terminando no meio, do outro lado", por exemplo: ABCDE, estando invertida, ficaria EDCBA, e fazendo ela começar no meio, CBAED.

Comment: I meant in a more practical sense. Do you want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: I would really like to see a flag -> close -> homework button.

Comment: Well guys, as I said, I'm new to C, sorry if I don't have enough knowledge to do this. Anyway, nevermind, just ignore this topic now on. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I will make it write like DEABC and then revert it, I was just trying to do it in another way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without telling you exactly the code to write, because you are asking for help with academic work, you can try this:

1. Read in a line of text.
2. Using the length of the line (`scanf` returns an int with the number of characters read if I'm not mistaken), loop through it backwards, printing each character at a time.
   Something to try would be like this:

   ```
    //This is pseudocode. Do not copy/paste
    for(int i = length of line; i > 0; i--) {
        print out line[i];
    }
   ```
3. Then divide the length by 2 and run two loops in reverse, one starting in the middle:

   ```
   //This is Psuedocode. Do not copy/paste
   for(int i = middle of line; i > 0; i--) {
       print out line[i];
   }
   ```

   And then another starting at the end:

   ```
   //This is Pseudocode. Do not copy/paste
   for(int i = length of line; i > middle of line; i--) {
       print out line[i];
   }
   ```
4. ????
5. Profit

Obviously, you will have to tweak a few things here and there. For example, `i = length of line` will cause a runtime error, but you're here to learn and I believe in learning by doing.

Comment: Thank you very much Joel, this was the light I was looking for, I'll try to implement the idea as soon as I'm in home.

Comment: No problem. I was once like you, completely new to C, so I get not knowing what to do. I find it helps to write down exactly what you want the program to do, using paper and ink, one sentence at a time. Then sift through the sentences looking for bits of information you'll need for calculations. These could be your variables. If you do some things more than once, these could be loops or functions. Each sentence should be easily translated into code. Breaking it down like that makes it easier. Do this over and over until it comes naturally. You'll be solving more complex stuff in no time.

Comment: "scanf returns an int with the number of characters read if I'm not mistaken" is a mistake.  `scanf()` nominally returns the number of _fields_ successfully scanned.

Comment: This is why I used pseudocode because I couldn't remember